# Deployment of full database dump still causes error

Tags: database, deployment

I want to deploy my local DB to a staging server.

The local DB dump was exported with all tables. Including the "cache_" prefix table structures with no data exported.

After deployed to staging (with Jenkins), I got exceptions like Plugin missing error or field missing.

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Unable to determine class for field type 'daterange' found in the 'field.storage.node.field_date_range' configuration" at /var/www/html/lightnest/releases/20200227152907/docroot/core/modules/field/src/FieldStorageConfigStorage.php line 164

I cannot run update.php or rebuild.php because this error will popup again.
I also cannot run drush commands as I have no direct access to the staging.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Drush commands remotely from another server using methods such as site aliases.
https://docs.drush.org/en/master/usage/#site-aliases

So you might be able to run registry rebuild https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

which sometimes helps with class errors.